# Update input value after validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I’m new to Vue.

I would like to know if it is possible to update the input value after running a custom validation in Vuelidate. I have an input field for postcode. I want to return the postcode with the correct format in case the user forgets to put a whitespace, and update the input field with the correct value, e.g.

user input = XXXXXX
returned output = XXX XXX

Sample code

```js
export default {
  ...
  validations: {
    postcode: {
      required,
      maxLength: maxLength(10),
      validatePostcode: (value) => {
        const result = customValidators.validatePostcode(value);
        if (result !== false) {
          if (result !== value) {
            // UPDATE THE INPUT VALUE HERE WITH THE CORRECT POSTCODE FORMAT
          }
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you share some code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Zero  I have updated my question above with some sample code. I've tried updating the value using the DOM API, but Vue reverts it at the end of this code block.

Comment: You can use v-mask for format validation like this, 
<input
     v-model="form.mobileNo"
     name="mobileNo"
     v-mask="'## ## ### ## ##'"
  >

Comment: @SanthoshKN I forgot to mention that the postcode field is used in conjunction with a list of countries in a dropdown. This form is for a global e-commerce app. So we're talking about a lot of mask formats here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the arrow function declaration to a function shorthand declaration. I'm now able to access the component object and change the input field value via the Vuelidate model. Thanks to this: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/237